# Aналог JNDI на C#

Tags: java, c#

Подскажите пожалуйста аналог (хотя бы примерно выполняющий такие же функции) [JNDI](http://java-online.ru/jndi.xhtml) в C#.

Comment: С удовольствием присоединяюсь к вопросу

Comment: А можно в двух словах для дотнетчиков, что это вообще такое?

Comment: @VladD конфигурируемый контейнер сервисов, из которого эти сервисы можно получить через Uri специального вида. Используется JavaEE-разработчиками как способ окончательно запутать свой код, сделав его неработоспособным без особого магического конфига который нельзя менять.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ынтерпрайзовщина? Не сталкивался с этим никогда, не знал. Спасибо!

Comment: @PavelMayorov, аналог Pimple? Или не?

Comment: @vp_arth сложно сказать. У интерпретируемых языков есть особенность: им не нужны отдельные конфиг-файлы, поэтому при системы построенные вокруг конфигов вырождаются во что-то тривиальное.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Прямого аналога JNDI в C# нет. Косвенным аналогом можно считать любой IoC-контейнер поддерживающий конфигурацию внешним файлом, например [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/windsor/)

Также у многих библиотек есть свои способы конфигурирования, особенно у системных.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, эту роль в .NET играет просто `System.Uri`. Он включает, кроме http- и файловых URI, ещё и псевдо-URI наподобие `ws://` (websocket), `ldap://` и другие.

Динамическое добавление новых схем проводится через `UriParser.Register`. Например, WPF регистрирует свою схему `pack://`, которая ссылается на WPF-ресурсы.

Comment: Можно из `System.Uri` получить от сервера приложений объект источника данных, преднастроенный администратором сервера? Или в .NET это иначе делается?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev: А что есть сервер приложений?

Comment: @VladD JNDI - это не особый формат Uri, а конфигурируемый контейнер объектов

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, я имел в виду скорее универсальную расширяемую адресацию объектов. «Конфигурируемый контейнер» никак не был понятен из исходного вопроса (а также из текста по ссылке из вопроса).

Comment: @VladD как - непонятен? По ссылке приведенной автором, пункт "Поиск ресурсов в JNDI, lookup". Там хорошо видно для чего JNDI используется на самом деле.